# How would I use the output of a set of instructions to make a new variable?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, unix, cut

So basically I have a variable, lets consider this variable v

```
v=overflow_12
```

Now I am doing a `cut -d` delimiting command at the `_` to split overflow and 12 of which I have done:

```
echo $v | cut -d '_' -f 2
```

which gives me the answer 12. However how would I store that 12 in a variable and eventually increment it by 1 to make 13?

I tried:

```
i= echo $v | cut -d '_' -f 2
```

which should store 12 into `$i`? However when I then:

```
echo $i
```

it is just a blank answer? I have to eventually increment this variable by 1 but I don't know why 12 is not being stored in `$i`?

Comment: In this case you don't need external commands, bash's parameter expansion can do it: `i="${v##*_}"`

Comment: With bash: `v=overflow_12; declare -i value="${v#*_}"+1; echo $value`?

Comment: Please don't deface your posts.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(command)` to capture the output of a command as a string.

```
i=$(echo $v | cut -d '_' -f 2)
```

Alternatively, you can strip off the prefix directly in bash.

```
i=${v#*_}
```

`#` removes a string prefix and `*_` matches anything followed by an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You're just using the wrong syntax for variable assignment. You can't use `|` to pipe into a variable, and you can't have a space after the `=`. This works:

```
v=overflow_12
i=$(echo $v | cut -d '_' -f 2)
echo $i
```

Answer (score 0):

Use i=$(command) to set i to result of command.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
i=$(echo $v | cut -d '_' -f 2)
```

which will work for most bash-versions, except very old ones. For ancient bash versions do

```
i=`echo $v | cut -d '_' -f 2`
```

I would suggest to use the "here string" syntax `<<<` instead of `echo`

```
i=$(cut -d '_' -f 2 <<< $v)
```